# Percorrer array em php

Tags: php

```
<?php 
$command = system('python usb.py');
echo "<br>";

$arr1 = str_split($command);
$c = 0;
$i = 0;

while ($c == 0) {
    if (strcmp($str1[$i], " ")) {
        $c = 1;
    }
        echo $arr1[$i];

    $i++;
}


?>
```

O código acima chama um aquivo python que retorna os dispositivos de armazenamento usb conectados no servidor, algo mais ou menos assim: `/media/adryan/MULTIBOOT /dev/sdb1`
tentei obter o valor retornado enquanto o valor contido no índice do array fosse diferente de um espaço mas a página não carrega ou da erro... alguém pode me ajudar com isso?

Comment: Manos, qual o erro acontece?

Comment: a pagina simplesmente nao abre